# Problem combining LEFT() and QUERY() functions

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm currently working in Google Sheets and I need to import a part of a row from a spreadsheet to another. I'm importing the row with the `QUERY()` function and "cutting" the data from the row with `LEFT()` function. Something like this:

```
=LEFT(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1MkAat5Q791H0UKOuGwMIz2d8crocbNecyF4jnXo9K58";
 "Notas 1ºA No Pivoteadas!A1:D527");"select Col1");8)
```

The problem is that only applies the `LEFT()` function to the first cell of the row and the whole row taken from the query is filled with the same cell.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- add continuosity with **`ARRAYFORMULA()`**: 


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(LEFT(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1MkAat5Q791H0UKOuGwMIz2d8crocbNecyF4jnXo9K58"; 
   "Notas 1ºA No Pivoteadas!A1:D527"); "select Col1"); 8))
  ```
- for number-text combo add **`TO_TEXT()`**:


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(LEFT(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE(
   "1MkAat5Q791H0UKOuGwMIz2d8crocbNecyF4jnXo9K58"; 
   "Notas 1ºA No Pivoteadas!A1:D527")); "select Col1"); 8))
  ```

Comment: Thanks! It solved the problem